# How many unique triangles could you make if you had n line segments with lengths that correspond to the first n natural numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

This problem came into my head, and I felt the urge to try and solve it:

"If you had $n$ line segments with lengths that correspond to the first $n$ natural numbers, how many unique triangles could you make?"

Another way you could say this is "in how many ways can we form a nondegenerate triangle by choosing three distinct numbers from the set of the first $n$ natural numbers as the sides?"

This question was inspired by a problem "The Art of Problem Solving, Volume 1", which asked for the answer for a specific case where you have the set of numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. In this case the answer is 3, because the only triples you can make that uphold the triangle inequality are (3,4,5), (2,4,5) and (2,3,4).

I attempted to work through the combinatorics to find a general solution for the first $n$ numbers. My general idea was to imagine three numbers $n_1$ < $n_2$ < $n_3$. I let $n_3$ be all natural numbers that are less than or equal to $n$. Then I let $n_2$ be any natural number less than $n_3$. Then I let $n_1$ be any number such that $n_1$ < $n_3$ - $n_2$ (so that is upholds the triangle inequality). From these facts I found this formula, which I think works:

$$\sum_{n_3=4}^{n} \sum_{n_2=1}^{n_3-1}\max\{0,2n_2-n_3-1\}.$$
If you evaluate this for $n=5$ you'll see that it equals 3, and I think it works for all other cases too. I could try to explain further how I derived this equation, but hopefully it will be obvious enough? The $n_3=4$ initialization for the same is because there simply won't be any valid triples when $n_3<4$. You could also initialize $n_3$ to 1 and it would work the same way, but it's just to save computation.

Here is a quick test I made that my solution works for the first 100 n:
https://gist.github.com/KDJDEV/6710eb45f8c9792f67bb1141fd6419df

Now, I was hoping to be able to find a simpler solution than this (preferably something without a double sum) My plan was to simplify the sum with sum rules, but unfortunately I don't think I can do that because of the max function. Is there a better way to solve this problem than what I've done?

Thanks!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002623

Comment: MathJax tip: You clearly know how to do display mode equations, by encasing Latex code in `$$` signs. You can also do the same code inline, encasing instead in single `$` signs. For example `This is how you write $n_3$ inline!` produces:$$ $$This is how you write $n_3$ inline!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about inline Latex! I updated the post so that it's prettier now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JMoravitz commented, this sequence is [sequence A002623](https://oeis.org/A002623) in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. In the comments they give the formula $\lfloor (n+2)(n+4)(2n+3) / 24 \rfloor$, but their indexing is different from the OPs, so $n$ needs to be changed to $n-4$ to match. The result can be written as
$$
\biggl\lfloor \frac{2 n^3-9 n^2+10 n}{24} \biggl\rfloor = \frac{4 n^3-18 n^2+20 n+3 (-1)^n-3}{48}.
$$

Comment: This is great, thanks! Do you know how I could go about deriving this formula from my formula involving the max function?

Comment: Induction might work; you can also try rewriting it as $$\sum_{n_3=4}^{n} \sum_{n_2=\lceil n_3/2 \rceil+1}^{n_3-1}(2n_2-n_3-1)$$and using standard formulas for sums of linear/quadratic polynomials.